# Bootstrap .affix - jQuery hasClass not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the Bootstrap .affix plugin and I'm trying to do something that the navbar when the affix class is added, but for some reason I can't seem to access the class once it is added to the navbar.

Keep in mind navbar is just a variable I created.

```
navbar.affix({
    offset: {
        top: header.height()
    }
});
```

The above code adds .affix class to my navbar after scrolling the height of the header, and when I look in Chrome developer tools I see the class is added for sure, but when I try to do something like this:

```
navbar.hasClass('affix', function() { // Do something });
```

The code above never get's called.. it's as if .affix is never added to the navbar.

Am I missing something here? Is it doing something I'm not aware of that is somehow blocking me from being able to access the .affix class?

Comment: Can you tell how navbar variable is assigned/populated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot assign a function to `hasClass` method. Instead use a true/false condition based on `hasClass` result to call your function.

> The .hasClass() method will return true if the class is assigned to an element ...

https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/

**EDIT**: I have checked which class gets added to the element using `navbar.attr('class')` and the result is `main-menu affix-top`. So if you check `hasClass('affix-top')` it should work. https://jsfiddle.net/yqy7gah6/14/

**EDIT 2**: You should better check for the presence of any one of these three classes to ascertain that `affix` has been applied: Here's how the affix plugin works: `affix-top`, `affix` and `affix-bottom`.
You could use `hasClass` with `OR` or you could better use jQuery [`is`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) like this:

```
if (navbar.is('.affix, .affix-top, .affix-bottom')) {
  // Do you stuff here
}
```

From Bootstrap's description of [Affix](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix):

> 1. To start, the plugin adds `.affix-top` to indicate the element is in its
>      top-most position. At this point no CSS positioning is required.
> 2. Scrolling past the element you want affixed should trigger the actual
>      affixing. This is where `.affix` replaces `.affix-top` and sets position:
>      fixed; (provided by Bootstrap's CSS).
> 3. If a bottom offset is defined,
>      scrolling past it should replace `.affix` with `.affix-bottom`. Since
>      offsets are optional, setting one requires you to set the appropriate
>      CSS. In this case, add position: absolute; when necessary. The plugin
>      uses the data attribute or JavaScript option to determine where to
>      position the element from there.

Comment: To your comment above, navbar is $('.main-menu'), which is a class on the nav element. That element also gets the .affix added to it, which is what I'm having a problem finding with jquery.

Comment: Mine has the class affix-top when at the top of the page, then when it becomes fixed, the affix-top is removed and replaced with affix. It's so strange, I don't understand why jQuery can't find the class.

Comment: See my 2nd edit ... there are actually 3 classes which could be added to your HTML element ...

Comment: @Lansana Please remember to mark it as answer, as I hope it has solved your problem now ...

Comment: Thanks for the great help. I've looked through the documentation and all, nothing seems to be working, but I will surely keep trying I must be missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using jquery .hasClass, it just returns true/false and does not accept a function;

```
if($(navbar).hasClass('affix'))
{ 
 CODE HERE  
};
```

Comment: Tried conditonials, functions, none of them work. It's like they're all ignoring .affix or .affix isn't being seen for some reason.

Comment: @Lansana, then perhaps it isn't there when your code executes?

Comment: I can't really use a JSFiddle as this is part of a larger project and it's on a development server so I can't really share it either. Grr, I normally just use plain javascript but bootstrap makes it a sinch.